# DXF export in QGIS giving hatches instead of polylines

Tags: qgis, autocad, dxf

I am new to QGIS, and using QGIS 2.0.1.

I'm having a problem when saving as .dxf. I export a building layer (polygons) as a .dxf file However in AutoCAD it turns up as a hatch instead of as a closed polyline which is what I'm looking for. I can of course recreate the boundary in AutoCAD, but I would rather just save the data correctly in QGIS.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Qgis uses GDAL's ogr2ogr to export between formats and from www.gdal.org, "Polygon and MultiPolygon features are written as HATCH entities", so the hatches in AutoCAD should be expected.  To generate closed polylines from the hatch objects use the AutoCAD command HATCHGENERATEBOUNDARY.

Additionally you could use the command OGR2OGR to export the shapefile to polylines using the following code:

```
"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" -f "DXF" file.dxf shapefile.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING
```